# Move navigation controller and add a label

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to move the navigation controller and add an small title between the default iphone bar and the navigation controller bar. Something like that:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6an4ywp5h1dnxy2/iphone.png

I have not idea how to do it. I'm trying to move the navigation controller with this code

```
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 54.0, 220.0, 556.0);
```

self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 210.0, 64.0);

but then i can't add the label.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acturely , navigationcontroller can not finish you job , you can use uiviewcontroller and uitoolbar,uinavigationbar to do that , hope it can help you .

and this is tutorial

[navigationbar tutorial](http://my.oschina.net/plumsoft/blog/55927)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you cannot move the default navigation bar of your navigationController.  That said, you could hide your navigationController's navBar, and then add a custom navBar (via xib or code) to your view (and set it however many pixels below the top you desire) and add a label above that.  Then just have the actions for button presses call the navigationController's button calls (or do it yourself).

That having been said, this whole UI would be an abnormal appearance and would probably feel weird...Not sure that I'd recommend it.

To hide the navigationController's bar:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank! I fix it it was a project problem (i started again and it works).